# how to change values between tags in a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have the following string:

```
str="hello %%one_boy%%'s something %%four_girl%%'s something more"
```

how would I edit it to get the following output from printing str:

```
"hello ONE_BOY's something FOUR_GIRL's something more"
```

I have been trying to use 'gsub' and 'upcase' methods but am struggling with the regex to get each word between my '%%' symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :066 > str.gsub(/%%([^%]+)%%/) {|m| $1.upcase}
 => "hello ONE_BOY's something FOUR_GIRL's something more"
```

The `[^%]+` says it will match 1 or more characters except %, and the [`$1`is a global variable that stores the back reference to what was matched.](http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
s.gsub(/%%([^%]+)%%/) { $1.upcase }
```

Comment: It works for me - the brackets are between the %%'s so the capture just includes the text between.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way:

```
"hello %%one_boy%%'s something %%four_girl%%'s something more".gsub(/(%%.*?%%)/) do |x|
    x[2 .. (x.length-3)].upcase
end
```

The `x[2 .. (x.length-3)]` bit slices out the middle of the match (i.e. strips off the leading and trailing two characters).

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to choose the delimiters, you might be able to use [String.interpolate](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/String.interpolate) from the Facets gem:

```
one_boy = "hello".upcase
str = "\#{one_boy}!!!"
String.interpolate{ str }    #=> "HELLO!!!"
```

But I'd first check that Facets doesn't cause any conflicts with Rails.

Answer (score -1):

```
str.gsub(/%%([^%]+)%%/) { |match| $1.upcase }
```